How it works a Recursive MySQL Query
I'm working on a mini project for warehouse management, and I need to manage the available quantity of items. Sometimes articles can be composed (made up of one or more different articles), which in turn can be composed of others.
Example: I have 100 L of water and 100 1L bottles in stock. I have the 'Water bottle' product made up of 1 L of water and 1 one-litre bottle.
I don't already have bottles in stock, but the theoretical quantity I could have is 100 bottles of water.
I have already created a Mysql table containing basic product information and a table in which I list the products needed and the quantity of them to create another product.
Example of Json data
{
    "products": [
        {"id": 1, "name": "Water", "quantity": 120, "compound": false, "decimal": true},
        {"id": 2, "name": "Bottles", "quantity": 240, "compound": false, "decimal": false},
        {"id": 3, "name": "Small Water Bottle", "quantity": null, "compound": true, "decimal": false},
        {"id": 4, "name": "Water Box", "quantity": null, "compound": true, "decimal": false},
        {"id": 5, "name": "Water Shelf", "quantity": null, "compound": true, "decimal": false}
    ],

    "compound_list": [
        {"id": 1, "compound_id": 3, "requirement_id": 1, "requirement_quantity": 1},
        {"id": 2, "compound_id": 3, "requirement_id": 2, "requirement_quantity": 1},
        {"id": 3, "compound_id": 4, "requirement_id": 3, "requirement_quantity": 6},
        {"id": 4, "compound_id": 5, "requirement_id": 4, "requirement_quantity": 10}
    ]
}

My problem is to create a recursive Query that calculates the quantity of composite products formed by composite products.
I would like to create a MySQL view but I don't understand how CTE recursion works with with functions.
All other answers didn't help me clear my doubts.
I created a query that works, but it only works with products made up of prime products
SELECT 
    art.id          AS product_id,
    art.name        AS product_name,
    art.qty         AS product_requirement_qty,
    art.compound
FROM
    articles art
WHERE 
    art.compound = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    art.id                      AS product_id,
    art.name                    AS product_name,
    MIN(
        CASE
            WHEN art.decimal = 1
            THEN ROUND( (art_calc.qty/lc.requirement_qty), 2)
            ELSE FLOOR( (art_calc.qty/lc.requirement_qty) ) 
        END 
    ) AS product_requirement_qty,

    art.compound
FROM
    articles art
    INNER JOIN 
        compound_list lc 
    ON lc.compound_id = art.id

    INNER JOIN
        articles art_calc 
    ON art_calc.id = lc.requirement_id

WHERE 
    art.compound = 1
GROUP BY 
    art.id;

I created a recursive function (not the most efficient in the world) of what I would like to receive in Node.js --> it works
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');
const { exit } = require('process');

const products = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Water",  "quantity": 100, "compound": false, "decimal": true},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Bottles", "quantity": 100, "compound": false, "decimal": false},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Small Water Bottle", "quantity": null, "compound": true, "decimal": false},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Water Box", "quantity": null, "compound": true, "decimal": false},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Water Shelf", "quantity": null, "compound": true, "decimal": false}
];

const compound_list = [
    {"id": 1, "compound_id": 3, "requirement_id": 1, "requirement_quantity": 1},
    {"id": 2, "compound_id": 3, "requirement_id": 2, "requirement_quantity": 1},
    {"id": 3, "compound_id": 4, "requirement_id": 3, "requirement_quantity": 6},
    {"id": 4, "compound_id": 5, "requirement_id": 4, "requirement_quantity": 10}
];


function ViewQty(products, compound_list){
    
    const startTime = performance.now();

    var tableQTY = [];

    products.forEach(product => {
        tableQTY.push(
            recursiveFunction(products, product, compound_list)
        );
    });

    const endTime = performance.now();

    console.table(tableQTY);

    
    const elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
    console.log(`Execution Time: ${elapsedTime}`);
}



function recursiveFunction(products, product, compound_list){
    if(!product.compound){
        return {
            "id": product.id,
            "name": product.name,
            "quantity": product.quantity
        };
    } else {
        var components = getComponents(product.id, compound_list);
        var minQty;

        if(components.length > 0){
            var possibleQtyList = [];
            components.forEach(component => {
                var x = products.find(art => art.id === component.requirement_id);

                var obj = recursiveFunction(products, x, compound_list);

                obj.quantity /= component.requirement_quantity;

                possibleQtyList.push(obj); 
            });

            minQty = Math.min(...possibleQtyList.map(element => element.quantity));
        } else {
            minQty = 0;
        }
        
        if(product.decimal){
            minQty = minQty.toFixed(2);
        } else {
            minQty = Math.floor(minQty);
        }

        return {
            "id": product.id,
            "name": product.name,
            "quantity": minQty
        };
    }
}

function getComponents(id, compound_list){
    
    var miniList = [];

    compound_list.forEach(element => {
        if(element.compound_id === id){
            miniList.push(element);
        }
    });
    
    if(miniList.length === 0){
        return {"requirement_id": null, "requirement_quantity": 0};
    } else {
        return miniList;
    }
}

ViewQty(products, compound_list);


I hope someone can help me, at least to understand how recursion works in mysql

Your scheme formally allows multiple solutions. For example components A and B can be combined to component С = A+2B or to component D = 2A+B. So the task is not solvable now. You must define some additional rule(s), similar to "Create N (or as many as possible) instances of component X" or "Create the component with the least ID from all ones which can be created from current amounts state" and so on.

For now I have solved the problem by creating a dynamic 'VIEW' created in my case with the php backend, creating a recursive function very similar to the one mentioned above, but improved
